# Will the differentiability of Fourier transform be very bad?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Though we know for any $f\in L^1(R)$, its Fourier transform $\hat{f}\in C_0$, what can we say about its differentiability? I'm trying to construct an example to make both $f,\hat{f}\in L^1$ but $\hat{f}$ is nowhere differentiable. Is this possible?

Comment: The function $f_\delta(t)= \max(0, 1- |t|/\delta)$ is $L^1$ and has $\sup_\delta \Vert \widehat{f_\delta} \Vert_1 < \infty$. So I think you should be able to build an $f$ of the form you are seeking, by stacking together scaled and shifted copies of $\widehat{f_\delta}$.

Comment: @Yemon  Choi Thank you! This is helpful. I will try to figure out this with your hint!

Comment: @Yemon Choi Could you please give more hint on the construction? I've been thinking on functions like $\sum2^n f_{3^n}(x-r_n)$, where $r_n$ is an enumeration of rational numbers, but I couldn't determine the differentiability of the function.